# What is the correct way to return an extra large string using NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, string, csv, ios7, nsurlconnection

The URL that I am connecting to is a php file outputting a very large amount of data in the form of a CSV output.

Right now everything works correctly and I am not receiving any errors using the NSURLConnection. However, when using connectionDidFinishLoading I am not receiving all the data. I am appending the data in didReceiveData. Sometimes I get more data than others, so it seems the connection is not staying open long enough to finish getting the data.

What is the correct way to use NSURLConnection to get an extra large string?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
- (void)checkDatabaseUpdate_Places
{

    NSString *post =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"some_parameters_here"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"site_url_here"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        placesTableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        placesTableVerification = @"getting data";
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Bad Connection for Places");
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    long long dataSize = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"expected data size: %lld", dataSize);

    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"getting data"]) {
        [placesTableData setLength: 0];
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"getting data"]) {
        [placesTableData appendData:data];
        placesTableVerification = @"got data";
    }

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFailWithError %@",error.description);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Defaults Could Not Load" message:@"There was an error loading your defaults. Make sure your device has an active internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    //Database Setup
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"database_name.db"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",_databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        }
    }

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    //start Places Table Update
    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"got data"]) {

        NSString *returnedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [placesTableData mutableBytes] length:[placesTableData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%lu -- %@",(unsigned long)[placesTableData length],returnedData);


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[returnedData componentsSeparatedByString:@"~~"]];

            NSString *tempItems = [[NSString alloc] init];

            for (tempItems in tempArray) {

                NSArray *itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                itemArray = [tempItems componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|"]];

                NSMutableString *loadDB = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PLACES (ID,NAME,TYPE,CATEGORY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY,CHAMBER_SECONDARY_CATEGORY,INFORMATION,PHONE,FAX,EMAIL,WEBSITE,PHYSICAL_ADDRESS,MAILING_ADDRESS,START_DATE,STOP_DATE,HOTSPOT_FACTOR,MODIFIED) VALUES ("];

                int lastIndex = [itemArray count];
                int count = 0;

                NSString *tempItem = [[NSString alloc] init];

                for (tempItem in itemArray) {
                    count++;
                    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , tempItem];
                    if (count != lastIndex && string.length != 0) {
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:tempItem];
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:@","];
                    }
                    else if (count == lastIndex && string.length != 0){
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:tempItem];
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                    }
                    else {
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\"\","];
                    }


                }
                //end for

                loadDB = [[loadDB substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, loadDB.length)] mutableCopy];

                [loadDB appendString:@")"];

                //NSLog(loadDB);

                const char *errMsg;

                const char *insert_stmt = [loadDB UTF8String];

                sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt,
                                   -1, &statement, &errMsg);
                NSLog(@"%s",insert_stmt);
                NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt,
                                               -1, &statement, &errMsg));
                NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Places Table Updated");
                }
                //end if
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Places Table Failed To Update");
                    //NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement));
                }
                //end else

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);

                NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

            }
            //end for

        }
        //end if

        sqlite3_close(_the_kearney_app_database);

        [startupProgress setProgress:0.3 animated:YES];

    }
    //end Places Table Update

}
```

Any help you can give me as to why I might not be getting the full output from the server is appreciated.

**Solution**

```
- (void)checkDatabaseUpdate_Places
{

    NSString *post =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"some_parameters_here"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"site_url_here"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        placesTableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        placesTableVerification = @"getting data";
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Bad Connection for Places");
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    long long dataSize = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"expected data size: %lld", dataSize);

    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"getting data"]) {
        [placesTableData setLength: 0];
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"getting data"]) {
        [placesTableData appendData:data];
    }

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFailWithError %@",error.description);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Defaults Could Not Load" message:@"There was an error loading your defaults. Make sure your device has an active internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    //Database Setup
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"database_name.db"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",_databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        }
    }

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    //start Places Table Update
    if ([placesTableVerification isEqualToString:@"getting data"]) {

        NSString *returnedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [placesTableData mutableBytes] length:[placesTableData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%lu -- %@",(unsigned long)[placesTableData length],returnedData);


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[returnedData componentsSeparatedByString:@"~~"]];

            NSString *tempItems = [[NSString alloc] init];

            for (tempItems in tempArray) {

                NSArray *itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                itemArray = [tempItems componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|"]];

                NSMutableString *loadDB = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PLACES (ID,NAME,TYPE,CATEGORY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,CHAMBER_PRIMARY_CATEGORY,CHAMBER_SECONDARY_CATEGORY,INFORMATION,PHONE,FAX,EMAIL,WEBSITE,PHYSICAL_ADDRESS,MAILING_ADDRESS,START_DATE,STOP_DATE,HOTSPOT_FACTOR,MODIFIED) VALUES ("];

                int lastIndex = [itemArray count];
                int count = 0;

                NSString *tempItem = [[NSString alloc] init];

                for (tempItem in itemArray) {
                    count++;
                    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , tempItem];
                    if (count != lastIndex && string.length != 0) {
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:tempItem];
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:@","];
                    }
                    else if (count == lastIndex && string.length != 0){
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                        [loadDB appendString:tempItem];
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\""];
                    }
                    else {
                        [loadDB appendString:@"\"\","];
                    }


                }
                //end for

                loadDB = [[loadDB substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, loadDB.length)] mutableCopy];

                [loadDB appendString:@")"];

                //NSLog(loadDB);

                const char *errMsg;

                const char *insert_stmt = [loadDB UTF8String];

                sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt,
                                   -1, &statement, &errMsg);
                NSLog(@"%s",insert_stmt);
                NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt,
                                               -1, &statement, &errMsg));
                NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Places Table Updated");
                }
                //end if
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Places Table Failed To Update");
                    //NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement));
                }
                //end else

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);

                NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

            }
            //end for

        }
        //end if

        sqlite3_close(_the_kearney_app_database);

        [startupProgress setProgress:0.3 animated:YES];

    }
    //end Places Table Update

}
```

Comment: The init method you use for the `NSURLConnection` starts loading immediately, but `placesTableData` is not yet intialized. What happens if you initialize `placesTableData` before `theConnection`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJDDIDG

Comment: Good question. I will try that now.

Comment: @MikeD Same result. It seems that the connection closes before it loads all the data and not that the data is not being captured quick enough. But I could be totally wrong about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With long data, you can get multiple `didReceiveData:` callbacks. So you have to append all of them, not stop after the first one.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveResponse%3a):

> The delegate should concatenate the contents
>   of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL
>   load.

Comment: Thank you for restating that. As it turns out my code was concatenating the contents of each data object. However I was changing my placesTableVerification inside the didRecieveData and my conditional statement was no longer true. This answer pointed me in the right direction to correcting my problem. I am updating my question with the solution.